# How do i create a nested list from a json data?

Tags: json

From JSON, I'm trying to build a nested list of nodes which should look like the expected result below:

`(html (head (meta title)) (body (ul (div) (div) (div)))` ; *I guess this is the right approach for an interface label*

This is the original data from `json-read-from-string`:

```lisp
(pp json-dom)
((tag . "html")
 (children .
           [((tag . "head")
             (children .
                       [((tag . "meta")
                         (children .
                                   []))
                        ((tag . "title")
                         (children .
                                   []))]))
            ((tag . "body")
             (children .
                       [((tag . "ul")
                         (children .
                                   [((tag . "div")
                                     (children .
                                               []))
                                    ((tag . "div")
                                     (children .
                                               []))
                                    ((tag . "div")
                                     (children .
                                               []))]))                                               
                        ]))]))
```

I will be grateful if you can please assist in helping to obtain the correct result.

This is what I have done  so far:

Starting with the recursive function, I'm faced with either invalid argument when testing with `listp` or nil result when testing the top argument with `vectorp`

```lisp
(defun sidetree (node) 
  (when (vectorp node) 
    (cons (cdr (assoc 'tag node)) 
          (sidetree 
            (assoc 'children node)
            ; (cdr (car (aref (cdr (assoc 'children json-dom)) 0)))
            ))))

(pp (sidetree json-dom))
nil"nil"
```

I tried using the `letrec` approach as well,

```lisp
(defun fliptree()
  (letrec
      ((untree (lambda (tr)
                  (list
                  (alist-get 'tag tr)
                  (append (apply-partially untree '(alist-get 'children node)) nil )
                  ))))
    (funcall untree json-dom)))
```

And got the following result. I don't know what I'm not doing right.

```lisp
(pp (fliptree))
("html"
  (128 "\302\300\303\301\"\"\207"
      [(closure
            ((untree closure #4
                    (tr)
                    (list
                      (alist-get 'tag tr)
                      (append
                      (apply-partially untree
                                        '(alist-get 'children node))
                      nil)))
            t)
            (tr)
          (list
          (alist-get 'tag tr)
          (append
            (apply-partially untree
                            '(alist-get 'children node))
            nil)))
        ((alist-get 'children node))
        apply append]
      6 "\n\n(fn &rest ARGS2)"))
​
​
​
```

Comment: I have edited the expected result

Comment: The parentheses/brackets in your original data do not seem to be complete, i.e. Emacs indicates that the last parenthesis does not match with the first parenthesis. Are you sure that you posted it correctly?

Comment: Can you please check again ?

Comment: I mean in the 'output' of `(pp json-dom)`.

Comment: I have truncated part of the result, otherwise, the list is long. should I paste all the results?

Comment: I have updated the json data now, everything is balanced.

Comment: Okay, I have removed the balancing part from my answer

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot

Comment: Your expected result is still inconsistent.  `meta` and `title` are not treated the same way as the essentially-identical sequence of three `div` elements.  It's incredibly hard to know what you're trying to achieve when you include such inconsistencies.  (If *you* don't know what you want, how is anyone else supposed to know?)

Comment: @phils, I have updated it.

Comment: You haven't?  The last edit pre-dates my last comment.

Comment: Please don't post the same question to StackOverflow and emacs.SE. Choose one to keep and delete the other. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can get 'more or less' the result that you want using the following function:

```lisp
(defun json-format (obj)
  (when obj
      (cons (let ((rest (cdr (car obj))))
              (if (vectorp rest)
                  (map 'list #'json-format rest)
                (intern rest)))
            (unless (= (length (cdadr obj)) 0)
              (car (json-format (cdr obj)))))))
```

Calling it with the data (where data is you 'original data'), `(json-format data)`, returns the following:

```lisp
(html (head (meta) (title)) (body (ul (div) (div) (div))))
```